# I have Custom jQuery for Accordion and iam using toggle function, if i click on 2nd tab 1st tab should be collapsed, which is not happening

Tags: jquery, html, css

> I have **Custom jQuery** for Accordion and iam using toggle
>   function, if i click on 2nd tab 1st tab should be collapsed, which is
>   not happening
>
> ```
> <p>Here is the code Demo for reference</p>
> ```

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/LRMMv/)

Thanks !

Comment: your reference is not working. fix it first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add something to close the other open children.

```
$('.tgt-accordion .head').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.tgt-accordian-content').stop().slideUp();
    $(this).closest('li').find('.tgt-accordian-content').not(':animated').slideToggle();
});
```

That will close all the open content blocks and open the new one at the same time.

Comment: Thanks its working now, and one more thing i need to add arrow up and down.. plz help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LRMMv/1/  I added a new class of active to the A element. You can use this class to give inactive ones a background arrow and active a different arrow.

Comment: I mean Default it should be "plus icon" for all the tabs, once it is clicked the current tab should be "minus icon"

Comment: yes this can be done with the active class being added in my jsfiddle. All you do is you add a CSS line for the a tag. Then for the a tag with the active class. The second one (the minus image background) will overwrite the default (plus image background)

Comment: Okay, let me try adding :-)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LRMMv/3/ see the backgrounds I added to the CSS section. Yuo replace the blue with your inactive image and pink with the active.  I also made a quick fix to fix the removal of the active class when closing an active tab in the JS

Comment: Can we add focus to "tgt-accordian-content" once we click on plus icon, so while in accessibility mode it reads the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('.tgt-accordion .head').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   $Current = $(this).closest('li').find('.tgt-accordian-content').not(':animated').slideToggle();
    $('.tgt-accordian-content').not($Current).hide();
                });
```

[DEMO Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/sudhAnsu63/4bZr4/)